# vb.net win32api pointer to integer array parameter

Tags: vb.net, winapi, pointers, icons

Because I need to extract an icon from a file, but not the first icon, I cannot use the vb.net icon extraction function. The WIN32API function that should do this expects a pointer to an integer array.

How can I provide this type as a parameter?

```
Declare Function ExtractIconEx Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ExtractIconExA" _
(ByVal lpszFile As String, _
ByVal nIconIndex As Integer, _
ByRef phiconLarge As Integer, _
ByRef phiconSmall As Integer, _
ByVal nIcons As Long) As Integer


    Dim icons As integer()
    ExtractIconEx("%systemroot%/shell32.dll", 15, icons, 0, 5)
```

I've taken a gander at the `System.Reflection.Pointer` class?/namespace?, but the documentation is sparse and less than sensible.

`IntPtr` doesn't provide support for arrays afaikt

Ok tx to Hans I've managed to correct the signature to:

```
<Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("shell32.dll", _
CharSet:=Runtime.InteropServicesCharSet.Auto)> _
Shared Function ExtractIconEx(ByVal szFileName As String, _
        ByVal nIconIndex As Integer, _
        ByRef phiconLarge() As IntPtr, _
        ByRef phiconSmall() As IntPtr, _
        ByVal nIcons As UInteger) As UInteger
End Function 

...

 Dim icons(8) As IntPtr, smicons(8) As IntPtr
    MsgBox(ExtractIconEx("%systemroot%/shell32.dll", 15, icons, smicons, 1))
    Try
        MsgBox(icons.Count)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message & " by " & ex.Source)

    End Try
...
```

The subsequent calls always cause an exception (`Value cannot be null`). I get a return value of `4294967295`, which is the maximum 32 bit integer value.

Any ideas how to tame this function and make it work?

Comment: http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32/ExtractIconEx.html

Answer (score 2):

```
    ByRef phiconLarge() As IntPtr, _
    ByRef phiconSmall() As IntPtr, _
```

The VB.NET declaration on that webpage has a bug, these arrays need to be passed ByVal, not ByRef.  Note how they got it correct in the example code on the bottom of the page.

I edited the page to correct the bug.